# Getting predictions for learner in fastai/pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, fast-ai

I am working on a text model which predicts which category the text belongs to (multiple category model). There are two files `train.csv`- having text samples and labels and `test.csv` - having text samples only.

I am using the fast.ai library and my learner is all set up and fine-tuned. Now I need to apply my learner on the `test.csv` file as done in Cell [38] in [this Kaggle Notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/lymenlee/toxic-comments-classification-fast-ai?ref=hackernoon.com&scriptVersionId=21752779&cellId=40)

```
preds, target = learn.get_preds(DatasetType.Test, ordered=True)
labels = preds.numpy()
```

*Note: Fast.ai v2 is not compatible with v1*

Since this code is written in fast.ai v1, I need to convert it to v2 as the above code does not run giving the error `NameError: name 'DatasetType' is not defined`. How do I make the model run on the test file? I have seen a lot of examples where the exact code ran nicely, however that was in v1.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Try to define `DatasetType.Test` in [some way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62881871/13832810), but that may not
   be happy with v2
2. Keep predicting and storing the results simultaneously. I tried to do the following, but the kernel died!

```
    predicted = []
    real = []
    for elem in range(test_df.shape[0]):
        row, clas, probs = learn_classifier.get_preds(test_df.iloc[elem])
        # append to the lists
```